# How can I make a SquashFS file the root file system when doing an iPXE boot?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nfs, pxe, squashfs

I have a system that works perfectly fine as iPXE boot server. Now I'm trying to make it use a SquashFS file as a root file system, instead of an NFS file system.

The current system uses iPXE configuration as the following (relevant lines shown), and it's working fine:

```
:retry
kernel http://${next-server}/installdcos/ubuntu_os/vmlinuz root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=${next-server}:/installdcos/ubuntu_os/nfsroot ro ip=dhcp BOOTIF=%(mac)s console=ttyS0,38400n8 console=ttyS1,9600n8 console=tty0  || goto retry
initrd http://${next-server}/installdcos/ubuntu_os/initrd.gz || goto retry
boot || goto retry
```

Now, instead of the booted system use `/installdcos/ubuntu_os/nfsroot` as the root file system, I want it to use a single SquashFS as root file system (I mean the system should mount it and then use it as the root file system).

For this, first I've created a file `ubuntu_os.squashfs` that holds the contents of `nfsroot` directory using `mksquashfs`. Then I've placed this `ubuntu_os.squashfs` file in `/installdcos/ubuntu_os/nfsroot` directory.

Now, in my iPXE configuration, I want to say: please get the `ubuntu_os.squashfs` via network, mount it as a SquashFS file system, and use it as your root file system (so that you will not have go over NFS again for invoking commands that reside in the root file system).

But when I try the following change for the **kernel** line in the configuration:

```
kernel http://${next-server}/installdcos/ubuntu_os/vmlinuz root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=${next-server}:/installdcos/ubuntu_os/nfsroot/ubuntu_os.squashfs ro rootfstype=squashfs ip=dhcp BOOTIF=%(mac)s console=ttyS0,38400n8 console=ttyS1,9600n8 console=tty0  || goto retry
```

And do an iPXE boot from a machine, it starts the iPXE boot process, and after printing some lines, it gets stuck at the following error:

```
  Begin: Retrying nfs mount ... Begin: Running /scripts/nfs-premount ... done.
  mount: Not a directory
  done
  Begin: Retrying nfs mount ... Begin: Running /scripts/nfs-premount ... done.
  mount: Not a directory
  done
  Begin: Retrying nfs mount ... Begin: Running /scripts/nfs-premount ... done.
  mount: Not a directory
  done
```

The error message makes sense, indeeed, `/installdcos/ubuntu_os/nfsroot/ubuntu_os.squashfs` is not a directory.

So what kind of parameter and value combination should I write for that kernel configuration line?

I've checked documentation such as http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/BootPrompt-HOWTO-3.html and https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/nfs/nfsroot.txt, but could not figure out what magic incantation I should pass to kernel (and the rest of the SquashFS boot tutorials I found consider the boot operation taking place from disk, and not PXE, or doing it LiveCD, which is not exactly like my case).

Answer (score 3):

To understand what's going on you need to know how Linux PXE boots.

1. The kernel `vmlinuz`  is transferred
2. The initrd `initrd.gz` is transferred
3. The kernel mounts initrd and starts its `init` script

initrd is an ultra-minimal Linux system containing the minimal functionality for connecting to (NFS) or retrieving (HTTP/CIFS) the "real" OS (in your case contained within `ubuntu_os.squashfs`), mounting it and finally "chrooting" into it.

A PXE ready `init` script is in charge of parsing the kernel variables, starting the net services, handling NFS, HTTP, CIFS, etc.
In most of the cases a particular `initrd.gz` is not able to deal with all the protocols mentioned above then you need to "customize" your `initrd.gz` or to create a "complementary" initrd providing the missing features when needed.

In your case your `init` script still think it has to mount an NFS directory and not a file; then if you want to use NFS you should mount the directory where your `ubuntu_os.squashfs` is located and next mounting the `ubuntu_os.squashfs` file. THis of course means patching `init` (and/or its associated components)

If you do not mind offering `ubuntu_os.squashfs` on a CIFS share you can see
what [Serva](http://vercot.com/%7Eserva/an/NonWindowsPXE3.html) does for PXE booting Ubuntu live distros; you will see there all the parameters for CIFS booting (I'm related to Serva development)

i.e. Ubuntu LTS 14.04 Desktop Live

```
[PXESERVA_MENU_ENTRY]
asset    = Ubuntu LTS 14.04 Desktop Live
platform = amd64
kernel   = /NWA_PXE/$HEAD_DIR$/casper/vmlinuz
append   = showmounts toram root=/dev/cifs initrd=/NWA_PXE/$HEAD_DIR$/casper/initrd.lz,/NWA_PXE/$HEAD_DIR$/casper/INITRD_N11.GZ boot=casper netboot=cifs nfsroot=//$IP_BSRV$/NWA_PXE_SHARE/$HEAD_DIR$ NFSOPTS=-ouser=serva,pass=avres,ro ip=dhcp ro
```

Comment: I think I'll have to do something similar to what is described at http://adam.younglogic.com/2012/03/shared-nothing-diskless-boot/ (I do not want NFS at all, I just want to retrieve my squashfs file during PXE booting, mount it on the booted system, and make that system use it as the root file system)

Comment: forget about that link; if you are booting an Ubuntu flavor just see Serva's page. take a look at the parameters based on the different Ubuntu flavors. Your best option is to use customize a Live distro creating your own `ubuntu_os.squashfs` then you can reuse the distro PXE capabilities

Answer (score 0):

If the init scripts are able to search for the squashfs without additional mounts, it should be possible to include squashfs in/as initrd.

in pcbios mode this could be done by adding it as an extra initrd line.
The difficult thing is to know where to place it for it to be found by the init scripts.
[iPXE documentation](https://ipxe.org/cmd/imgfetch) shows a .ko module as an example.

in EFI mode, it get's a bit more complicated, but recent iPXE also has support to wrap any file in cpio headers, but that is a little bit different.

Comment: any chance you can point to info on how this might be done in EFI mode?

Comment: @aggieNick02 with recent iPXE it actually isn't any different at all. At https://gentoo.ipxe.se you can see example that works in EFI mode with older iPXE as well